# First blog post full width and the rest in grid format

Tags: css, wordpress, multiple-columns, blogs, elementor

I am trying to make the first blog post (i.e. the most recent one) full width at the top of the page and have the rest of the posts in a two column grid format below this. Ideally, I would like to do this using CSS. I haven't been able to find anything on the internet that works for me yet.

Any help is super appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide more context? how are you looping over your posts?  If you are using Elementor you could simply create a section that always displays the first post.  Then a section below it that always excludes the first post, then you can style your sections however you want.

Comment: grid children can span rows or columns, flex can wrap. what have you done so far ?

Comment: @VladimirMujakovic I am not entirely sure what "looping" means. Trying to figure it out- I'm sorry, this is my first time trying my hand at anything website-related. That's a great idea about the separate sections!

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I have  not done much with the setup of this page yet- I've been trying to figure out whether there is a way to do what I want without altering my theme's php files, which seems risky for a newbie. What is flex?

Comment: @Tempest, looping meant that you iterate over a collection of elements or pieces of data and perform an action on them.  In your case, your posts would be a collection, so you could display your collection of posts and omit the first post, because you are going to display it seperately in a different section.